# Abstract GORM Data Service not Being Injected by Spring

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm, aws-codepipeline

I have a GORM Data Service abstract class that I'm trying to wire it into a Controller class.  Given the below sample code as-is, the myDomainClassDataService object will be null when the application starts and I will get an exception when I attempt to call its methods.  If I apply the @Autowired annotation to myDomainClassDataService in the MyController class, then I will receive a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.  We are using GORM with a neo4j database.

The code works when running through IntelliJ locally, but not at all when built and deployed in an AWS CodePipeline.  This is part of an upgrade from Grails v4 to v5, where the code was previously working without any issues.

```
// gradle.properties
grailsVersion=5.1.7
grailsGradlePluginVersion=5.1.3
groovyVersion=3.0.7
springBootVersion=2.6.6
spring-framework.version=5.3.19
gormVersion=7.2.1
```

```
// Sample GORM Data Service class
import grails.gorm.services.Service
import org.myorg.auth.UserService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource

@Service(MyDomainClass)
abstract class MyDomainClassDataService {

    UserService userService

    MessageSource messageSource

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("messageSource")
    final void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource
    }

    abstract MyDomainClass get(Serializable id)

    abstract List<MyDomainClass> list(Map args)

    abstract Long count()

    abstract void delete(Serializable id)

    abstract MyDomainClass save(MyDomainClass myParam)

    def updateMyDomainClassApplicability(MyDomainClass myDomainClass, Boolean selectedApplicableFlag) {
        // Concrete method.  Do something.
    }

    def getSomethingFromMyDomainClass(myParam){
        // Concrete method.  Do something.
    }
    
    // More concrete methods below.
}


// Sample Controller class
import org.myorg.assessment.MyDomainClassDataService

class MyController {

    MyDomainClassDataService myDomainClassDataService

    def index(Integer max) {
        // Concrete method.  Do something.
    }
    
    // More concrete methods below.
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some of the information at https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/202 might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @Jeff Scott Brown.  I tried the "workaround" from the link you provided, as well as, what you suggested near the end of that issue (i.e., using the Lazy and Autowired annotations).  Unfortunately, neither one of those options worked for me.  I still get the org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception.

Comment: @Mike Have you solved this? I'm having similar problems.

Comment: I posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314181/gorm-data-services-are-not-injected-when-deployed-to-tomcat

Comment: @brianjohnsen I was not able to resolve the issue.  I ended up converting the GORM data service classes to regular/concrete Grails service classes.  For the abstract get(), list(), etc. methods that were originally in our GORM data service classes, I removed them from the regular Grails service classes I created and simply refactored our code to use the available methods directly from the related domain classes.

Comment: @Mike thanks for answering. I'm considering doing the same :-(

Comment: I had the same issue multiple times with an abstract data service and was able to resolve it with a simple `./gradlew clean`, but I don't know what caused it. Interface data services don't seem to have this problem.