# GORM Data Services are not injected when deployed to Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, grails, dependency-injection, grails-orm

Why are GORM Data Services are not injected into ordinary Grails services when deployed to Tomcat?

We have a couple of domain/service/dataservice sets like the following:

```
//grails-app/services
class BeerService {
    BeerDataService beerDataService

    List<BeerEntity> list() {
        beerDataService.list() << throws NPE
    }
}

//grails-app/services
@grails.gorm.services.Service(BeerEntity)
interface BeerDataService {
    List<BeerEntity> list()
}

//grails-app/domain
class BeerEntity {
    String type
}
```

This works as expected using `bootRun` or as a runnable jar (in any environment), but when deployed in Tomcat (8 or 9) the data services are not registered as beans (aka. not present in `applicationContext`).

Using them therefore results in NPE’s.

Fetching them from the `applicationContext` directly (via `@Autowired` or `Holders`) results in `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` being thrown.

I’ve verified the problem in a sample project (using `generate-all`) deployed to a local Tomcat 8 using different Java 8 versions.
Data Services are not injected when running in Tomcat, neither in controllers nor other services.

Any thoughts on why?
I’m completely lost!

**Environment:**

Java: `8.0.322-tem` and `8.0.302-open` 
Tomcat: `9.0.31` and `8.5.78` 
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

From `gradle.properties`:

```
grailsVersion=5.1.7
groovyVersion=3.0.7
gorm.version=7.2.1
```

Comment: I have the same problem.  I don't remember how I fixed it.  I read somewhere there is a bug or a circular reference to the service or something.  I think I fixed it by add a line @Autowired before BeerDataService beerDataService

Comment: @tom6502 As mentioned, if I add `@Autowired` it throws a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, and if I don't the dataservice is just `null`.

Comment: I created a [github issue](https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/563) in the GORM project

Comment: I’m using  `bootWar` as the build target and if I switch to using the `war` target everything works and the data services are injected again.

It seems that the Spring Boot runnable jar stuff ruins the DI of data services.